# How to make a MultiMock Http Callout Test for Salesforce?

Tags: testing, post, get, httprequest, apex

If I have an Apex function that is named `authorize()` that just gets a username, password, and session token, and another function called `getURL('id#', 'key')`, that takes an id# for the record as a string and a key for the image to return as a string as parameters. getURL calls the authorize function inside it in order to get the credentials for its callout. The authorize is a post request, and the getURL is a get request.

I am trying to figure out how to test both of these callouts just so I can make sure that getURL is returning the proper JSON as a response. It doesn't even have to be the URL yet which is its intention eventually. But I just need to test it to make sure these callouts are working and that I am getting a response back for the 75% code coverage that it needs.

I made a multiRequestMock class that looks like this:

```
    public class MultiRequestMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
        Map<String, HttpCalloutMock> requests;

        public MultiRequestMock(Map<String, HttpCalloutMock> requests) {
            this.requests = requests;
        }

        public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
            HttpCalloutMock mock = requests.get(req.getEndpoint());
            if (mock != null) {
                return mock.respond(req);
            } else {
                throw new MyCustomException('HTTP callout not supported for test methods');
            }
        }

        public void addRequestMock(String url, HttpCalloutMock mock) {
            requests.put(url, mock);
        }
    }
```

I then began to write a calloutTest.cls file but wasn't sure how to use this mock class in order to test my original functions. Any clarity or assistance on this would be helpful Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in your `calloutTest` class you use `Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MultiRequestMock(mapOfRequests));` then call the `getUrl` and/or `authorize` methods and instead of the request really executing the response returned will be that which is specified in the `response(HttpRequest)` method you have implemented in the `MultiRequestMock` class. That is basically how I see it working, for more info and an example you can see [this resource on testing callout classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm). This will get you the code coverage you need but unfortunately cannot check you are getting the correct JSON response. For this, you may be able to use the dev console and Execute Anonymous?

You may want to look at simplifying your `HttpCalloutMock` Implementation and think about removing the map from the constructor as this class really only needs to return a simple response then your `calloutTest` class can be where you make sure the returned response is correct.
Hope this helps

Comment: This worked thank you so much. I used a third party app for the JSON response called postman and it passed the code coverage test.

Comment: Awesome @chaseter15 happy to help